# Chooser Intent - Pick from gallery or camera

Tags: android, android-intent

So I managed to create a chooser intent to pick image from gallery or take a photo. The problem I am facing is that when I choose Camera and take a photo on returning back to my activity I receive the error that my application has stopped working unexpectedly whereas when I am using my gallery or google+ photos or file explorer then it's working totally fine. I am not able to figure out the error. Following is my code of starting the intent and handling the activity result:

*Function that starts the intent, called on the click of an ImageView:*

```
private void openImageIntent() {

    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
}
```

The `onActivityResult` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode, requestCode, returnIntent);
    if(requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if(returnIntent == null)
            {
                isCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                final String action = returnIntent.getAction();
                if(action == null)
                {
                    isCamera = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if(isCamera)
            {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri; 
                ivProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); //Troublesome

            }
            else
            {
                selectedImageUri = returnIntent == null ? null : returnIntent.getData();
                ivProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); //Perfectly fine.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know why is this happening, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

And of course, the logcat:

> 01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.footstapps.letsmeet/com.footstapps.letsmeet.ProfileInfoActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity
>   {com.footstapps.letsmeet/com.footstapps.letsmeet.ProfileInfoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1,
>   data=null} to activity
>   {com.footstapps.letsmeet/com.footstapps.letsmeet.ProfileInfoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3374)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  ... 12 more 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-29 16:19:40.886:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   com.footstapps.letsmeet.ProfileInfoActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileInfoActivity.java:160)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322) 01-29
>   16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3370)
>   01-29 16:19:40.886: E/AndroidRuntime(14234):  ... 13 more

**EDIT:**
I debugged the application and initialized the `selectedImageUri` with `Uri.EMPTY`. This removed the error but now the ImageView is not getting update however it's updated when I select image from gallery.

Comment: @EagleEye When I empty the statements in the if(isCamera) block, then it's working fine. The problem is with the assignment of selectedimageUri.

Comment: Make sure your `Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory)` is not returning null or empty

Comment: @PedroOliveira no, it's returning this: `file:///storage/sdcard0/MyDir/img_1422530590337.jpg`

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.footstapps.letsmeet/com.footstapps.letsmeet.ProfileInfoActivity}:  this line clearly says its returning null data

Comment: @EagleEye And he is not using the data at all so there's no problem with that.

Comment: Try removing the super call from `onActivityResult` @MohammadAreebSiddiqui

Comment: @PedroOliveira i removed it, the error is gone but it's not working.

Comment: And what's the content of `outputFileUri` when you get to `onActivityResult`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I receive the error that the app has stopped working when I try to log it's value in the onActivityResult method

Comment: Try using `new Handler().postDelayed()` to get it's value.

Comment: @PedroOliveira Now I get a nullPointerException. :P

Comment: I think that Android is clearing your memory when you go to the camera and therefore it's clearing your variable. Try implementing `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save that value

Comment: @PedroOliveira I have never used that before. I read the documentation but I do not know how do I save a variable. Do i need to save it in a bundle or something like that? or return a bundle

Comment: Check this code on how to do that https://gist.github.com/kanytu/7c96d90c6d79679a8f96

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69808/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-pedro-oliveira).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently Android was clearing the memory or opening a new activity instead of resuming the last one. Saving the current state of the activity would solve this problem. For this example you need to save the variable that has the uri of the image.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("outputFileUri",outputFileUri);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    outputFileUri = savedInstanceState.getString("outputFileUri");
}
```

Since  `onRestoreInstanceState` will be called before `onActivityResult` the value of `outputFileUri` will not be null.